# Change the time on a specified date with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want change the time on a specified date, i tried as following js code, but doesn't work `if...` in line number 11. What do i do?

```
var interval = self.setInterval("clock()", 1000);
function clock() {
    var date = new Date();
    var hourOffset = 3;
    date.setUTCHours(date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes());
    var time = date.getTime();
    date.setUTCFullYear(date.getUTCFullYear(), 3, 21);
    var dstStart = date.getTime();
    date.setUTCFullYear(date.getUTCFullYear(), 9, 22);
    var dstEnd = date.getTime();
    if (time > dstStart && time < dstEnd) hourOffset = 4; // This is line 11
    date.setUTCHours(date.getUTCHours() + hourOffset, date.getUTCMinutes() + 30);
    var output = date.getUTCHours() + ":" + date.getUTCMinutes() + ":" + date.getUTCSeconds();
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = output
}
```

​
I mean is this line that doesn't work:

`if (time > dstStart && time < dstEnd) hourOffset = 4;`

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bFzny/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the date functions, but I can tell you that time is less than dstStart, which is why hourOffset is staying at 3. Also, months are 0 based indices, not 1 based. March would be 2, while September would be 8. http://jsfiddle.net/bFzny/4/ This might help you some. Remember, when using jsfiddle you don't need to enclose the code in  tags.